# Are there infinitely many primitive Pythagorean triples for which 2 of the sides are prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I use $a=m^{2}-n^{2}=(m-n)(m+n)$, $b=2mn$, and $c=m^{2}+n^{2}$. So I can start on making $a$ prime by letting $m=n+1$, giving $m^2-n^2=(m-n)(m+n)=2n+1$, and then choosing values of $n$ so that $2n+1$ is prime. Then $c=m^{2}+n^{2}=(n+1)^{2}+n^{2}=2(n^{2}+n)+1$, and we similarly need values of $n$ so that $2(n^{2}+n)+1$ is prime. I can imagine there being infinitely many values of $n$ that make each expression prime ($c$ being less obvious), but I am unsure how one could conclude that there are (or there are not) infinitely many $n$ for which both $a$ and $c$ are prime.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A048161 implies it's an open question ("*conjectured that there are an infinite number of such*").

Comment: As $b$ cannot be prime, you must have $a$ and $c$ prime, and hence $a=2n+1$ for some positive integer $n$. Equivalently $a$ is any prime $p>2$. Then
$$c=2n^2+2n+1=\frac{(2n+1)^2+1}{2}=\frac{p^2+1}{2}.$$
So your question boils down to: Are there infinitely many prime numbers $p$ for which $\tfrac{p^2+1}{2}$ is prime? Whether an (irreducible) univariate polynomial is prime infinitely often (on the integers), is generally open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$a^2+b^2=c^2\iff\begin{cases}a=m^2-n^2\\b=2mn\\c=m^2+n^2\end{cases}$$ the only candidates to be primes are $a$ and $c$ which happen only when $m=n+1$. It follows the equation in primes $p$ and $q$ $$p^2+1=2q$$The proposed question leads to know if this last equation has infinitely many solutions which is a variant of the still non proved conjecture of Bunyakovsky generalizing the Dirichlet's theorem on the infinitude of primes in arithmetical progressions.This is a very hard question and for the second degree you can see at the paper of
Betty Garrison: **Polynomials With Large Numbers of Prime Values**." The American Mathematical Monthly, 97(4), pp. 316–317 in which is studied the number possible of primes for irreducible polynomials of degree two (but not for $p^2+1$ but for $x^2+1$ and not giving twice a prime, $2q$ but a prime $q$ so the proposed problem here  it's even more difficult).

Answer (score 0):

Comment: A family of Pythagorean triples can be found as:

$a=2 n+1$

$b=2n(n+1)$

$c=2n(n+1)+1$

$(n, a, b, c)=(1,3, 4, 5), (2, 5, 12, 13), (5, 11, 60, 61)\cdot\cdot\cdot$

Comment: Your fourth example is wrong.

Comment: @Piquito, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You are welcome. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be prime, then $p,\frac{p^2-1}2,\frac{p^2+1}2$ is a primitive Pythagorean triple. According to Euler, $\frac{p^2+1}2$ will be prime of the form $4x+1$ or a product of primes of the form $4x+1$.

It seems reasonable that the infinite sequence $((p^2)+1)/2$ for successive primes doesn't quit giving you primes, but I cannot supply a proof.

Comment: No one else can supply a proof yet. It's an unsolved conjecture. :)